# Replace multiple of the same char in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, char

I am working on a "guess the secret word" game in Java.  I have a char array containing `_`'s relative to the amount of letters in the secret word.  I am writing a method that will replace the `_`'s with the guessed letter.  My problem is when I have multiple of the same letters; only the first occurrence is replaced.  This is my code:

```
public void replaceBlank(char letter){
    if(guessLetter(letter)==true){
        int x=getSecretWord().indexOf(letter);
            charArray[x]=letter;
        }
   }
```

The code inside the if is the piece that deals directly with replacing the `_`'s.  I'm thinking that I need a for loop, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Side note: `if(guessLetter(letter))` is enough

Comment: You have to loop through the whole array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns only the index of the first occurrence of a character. Instead of using it, I'd treat the secret word as an array and just iterate over it:

```
public void replaceBlank(char letter) {
    char[] secret = getSecretWord().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < secret.length; ++i) {
        if (secret[i] == letter) {
            charArray[i] = letter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `getSecretWord()` returns a `char[]`.

Comment: @m0skit0 arg, was missing a call to `toCharArray()` there - fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can keep `secret` as a `String` and use `secret.charAt(i)` to access the characters. That will save copying the characters out of the string to create the char array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the whole array, for each index check if it's the letter, then replace.